# Tracking request before redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

App has a lot of tests, and issue is that only authenticated users can view them. So when there are not, app redirects them to sing_in/login_as_guest page. For example user sings in or logs in as guest, after that I want to redirect them to the page they were actually going to.
But I have no idea from where to begin, and is this possible? 
Can you please give me a key from where to begin?r

Comment: what testing framework are you using and what authentication system?

Comment: yep, user can authenticate via FB or with email/password or as temporary guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def login
    if User.authenticate(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])
      referer = params[:referer] || session[:referer] || request.referer
      flash.notice = 'Login succeeded'
      redirect_to referer || root_path
    else
      flash.alert = 'Login failed'
      redirect_to user_login_path
    end        
  end
end
```

Now when you want to redirect back from somewhere, just add a referer path to either a param, the session or the request, and it will redirect back on success.

Answer (score 0):

the end of chapter 5 and chapters 6,7,8,9 are step by step guide of what you need exactly 
[rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

Comment: no, friend, just giving 5 chapters can hardly be a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the simple solution, works pretty well for me. Application controller:

```
    if @current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
        return true
      else
      redirect_to root_url
      session[:was_going]=request.path #here I start session if request causes redirection
      end
  end
```

This method returns that request, if it exists

```
 def root_or_request
    if session[:was_going]
    path=session[:was_going]
    session[:was_going] = nil
    return path
    else
    return root_url
    end

  end
```

And than after starting session I just redirect with calling this method.